# Reading several byte[] from DataInputStream

Tags: java, stream

What I need to do is send multiple files using DataStreams. I'm doing this by sending the name of the file, and then the file's bytes. I need to send an undetermined number of files though. Here is the `DataOutputStream` code.

```
            out.writeUTF(path);
            out.write(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
```

It does that for each file that needs to be sent. But I don't know how to read it correctly with `DataInputStream`. This is what I have so far.

```
    while (in.available() != 0) {
        String path = in.readUTF();
        byte bytes = in.readByte();
    }
```

Obviously it wouldn't work, since it is only reading one byte. But I don't know how to make it read all of the bytes. Since there are several files being sent, `available()` would only equal 0 when the end of all the files are read, I think. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Something I completely forgot to mention, I want to be able to send a large file without running out of memory, and I don't think this would work. I think I would need to use a buffer, but I don't know what class supports that with files.

Comment: Why are you writing each byte separately instead of writing the whole byte array in one go?

Comment: @JonSkeet No particular reason. Would it be better to do it that way?

Comment: How did you init your DataInputStream. Are you sure it is init correctly? Have you step through and determined that it is reading only once, and dies? Is what you reading really the content of the file, or are you reading nothing because init was not correct?

Comment: @Churk I am using `new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream())`

Comment: Here is a quick reference to read a file into byte array; http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/File2ByteArray.html

Comment: @Churk That is not my problem.

Comment: @Stripies: Yes: `out.write(bytes);`

Comment: not to be curious, why are you reading files through socket, and not through filereader? you are reading the files locally to be sent right?

Comment: @Churk No, they are being sent from different machines.

Comment: do this instead `while(in.available()!=0) { read a chunk at a time and write it }`

Comment: So you are a receiver, not the sender. Oh I c, and you want to write out the file.

Comment: I updated the question. I forgot to add a detail.

Comment: @Stripies: this is a little more difficult than it first seems; you are basically inventing your own transfer protocol. If the files are known to be smaller than a few megabytes, I'd look into protocol buffers (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and send each file in a GPB message enhanced with metadata (file name, file size etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anytime you send variable length messages you need some way to mark the beginning and end of each method.

```
 List<File> files = someListOfFilesYouWantToSend;
 out.writeInt(files.size());
 for(File file : files){
   out.writeUTF(path);
   out.writeLong(file.getTotalSpace());
   out.write(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
 }
```

Then to read it you would do something like this

```
int filesToRead = in.readInt();    
for(int i = 0; i < filesToRead; i++){
  String path = in.readUTF();
  long bytesToRead = in.readLong();      
  FileOutputSteam fos = new FileOutputStream(path);

  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  while(bytesToRead > 0){
    bytesRead = in.read(buffer,0,bytesToRead > buffer.length ? buffer.length : bytesToRead);
    bytesToRead -= bytesRead;
    fos.write(buffer);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way to do it... Why won't you simply archive all the files you want to send in an archive (like a JAR or ZIP)? On the receiving side you can extract the archive. Java has a built-in JAR implementation (in package java.util.jar) that you can use.

Comment: That is just an opinion of implementation, and zipping or jaring things may not be on an option. Becareful to state `That's not the way to do it` unless you are an export in the field.

Comment: Well, obviously I am offering an implementation to the question asked here. Why isn't it an option? I think, for instance, that GMail transfers multiple file attachments in an archive.

Comment: What Gmail does, doesn't mean its best practice, and gmail does allow you to download one by one, so what is your point? Telling someone is not the way to do something because your opinion is more valid? You haven't offer any valid solution to a technical question, you overview another implementation that you offer no working code to support your claim. Let try to look at what the author is trying to fix then to add more to his problem.

Comment: I'm just presenting a solution that, in my opinion, offers a better approach to the problem at hand. I don't see the point in being stubborn about solving a problem in a particular way. There are of course many other good ways for doing it. I am just offering one.

Comment: @smichak But if there are multiple big files (10GB), wouldn't it run out of memory?

Comment: You don't have to archive the files in memory or on disk. You can use JarOutputStream and JarInputStream as wrappers for your output and input streams respectively. Use the putNextEntry method for each file you wish to add to the stream.

Comment: Here's a link to the package: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html